# When i used a timer decorator for multiple processes, the result is wrong

Tags: python, multiprocessing, decorator

**Here is my code.**

```
# this decorator is used to record the running time.
def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        stop_time = time.time()
        cost_time = stop_time-start_time
        print(f'cost time: {cost_time} s!')
    return wrapper

# caculate_and_save is my target function.
@timer
def multi_process():
    process_list = []
    gzdhb_df = pd.read_excel(io='./raw_data/各站点海拔.xlsx')
    for province in province_list:
        province_array = gzdhb_df[gzdhb_df['省份']==province].values
        p = Process(target=caculate_and_save, kwargs={'province': province, 'province_data': province_array}) 
        process_list.append(p)
        p.start()
    l = len(process_list)
    while True:
        for p in process_list:
            if not p.is_alive():
                l -= 1
        if l <= 0:
            break
```

**The printout of the program is shown in the figure below. Why does the runtime print when the first process is executed, instead of printing at the end of all processes?**
[printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuXgh.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, as an aside, your `timer` decorator will not work with functions that return results. You should save the result of calling `func` and then finally return that result after you print out the timings. Now for your main problem:

You have started some number of `Process` instances in `process_list`. Let's imagine that in your `while True:` loop you finally find a process that is no longer alive. Let's call it `p1` just to name it. You then subtract 1 from variable `l`. The next time through the loop, even if no further processes have terminated, you will still find that process `p1` is no longer alive and even though all processes except for `p1` are still alive, you will be decrementing `l` again because of `p1`. In short, once you discover that first process being no longer alive, every subsequent time through the loop you are guaranteed to be decrementing `l` at least once. Eventually `l` will go negative and you will break out of the loop with possibly only a single process having terminated.

I would suggest you wait for all processes to terminate by calling `join`:

```py
# this decorator is used to record the running time.
def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        stop_time = time.time()
        cost_time = stop_time-start_time
        print(f'cost time: {cost_time} s!')
        return result
    return wrapper

# caculate_and_save is my target function.
@timer
def multi_process():
    process_list = []
    gzdhb_df = pd.read_excel(io='./raw_data/各站点海拔.xlsx')
    for province in province_list:
        province_array = gzdhb_df[gzdhb_df['省份']==province].values
        p = Process(target=caculate_and_save, kwargs={'province': province, 'province_data': province_array}) 
        process_list.append(p)
        p.start()
    for p in process_list:
        p.join()
```